# Optimal Site Location Analysis

Tags: qgis, network-analyst

I'm using QGIS 3.4.  I have a point shapefile representing population density, and I would like to identify the 12 most optimal locations for service centers that would  serve the maximum amount of people in a given area. (See screenshot[image])

I tried the "K means clustering tool", which essentially plugs through multiple iterations that assign each point to the nearest cluster until the optimum number of clusters requested (in this case 12) are reached; However, the tool doesn't seem to be working, the outpoint is a duplicate of the input points shapefile.

I've used Network Analyst for a similar project in ArcGIS (see screenshot, the firework clusters are the optimal locations identified as a result of the cluster analysis), but I don't know how to proceed in QGIS.  Suggestions?

Comment: The K means tool output WILL look similar to the input - but it will have an additional attribute defining the assigned cluster.

Comment: Thank you, ndawson.  I expected the output to look different.  I used the "mean coordinates" tool to find the centroid for each of the 12 clusters.  In addition to population density, we also want to consider unemployment & poverty when determining the optimal 12 locations.  I have block group polygons containing unemployment & poverty rates.  Is there a way to use the k means tool to weight these 3 variables in terms of importance (population density=1, unemployment=2, poverty=3)?